# Tkinter - window focus loss event

Tags: python, tkinter, window, focus

Is there some event triggering when `tkinter` window loses focus that can be bound to a `tkinter` window using the `.bind` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tk/Tkinter: Detect application lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089068/tk-tkinter-detect-application-lost-focus)

Comment: See [Event types](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html) (since @j_4321's link no longer works).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `<FocusOut>`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_focus_out(event):
    if event.widget == root:
        label.configure(text="I DON'T have focus")

def on_focus_in(event):
    if event.widget == root:
        label.configure(text="I have focus")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(width=30)
label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in)
root.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am using `window.overrideredirect(True)` and with this it does not work.

Comment: @JakubBláha: you need to add that detail to your question.

Comment: Althought Bryan Oakley is right, you need to mention such details, it still works perfectly for me. I don't know if it's dependend on the OS (thats also an information missing in your question though) but it works well on Windows 10 Home (Python 3.7, Tcl/Tk 8.5).

Comment: Is it possible for tkinter window to never have focus but still be able to click buttons staying on top? Like on screen keyboard?