# .exe disappeared after go elsewhere

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

I have made a **.exe app with a .py and cx_Freeze**.
I can open my app and place it in my Windows taskbar at the bottom of the screen, but when I open it this **doesn't open a tab** like when you open an app a tab appears and when I go elsewhere **my app disappears**… I can see that my app is in the **task manager** but really nowhere…

**UPDATE**: All of that is due to this line: `win.overrideredirect(True)`
in my app's code but I don't know what to do, I found nothing…

```
# -*- Encoding:Latin-1 -*-
import os 
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font


win = tk.Tk()
win.overrideredirect(True)
win.geometry('+400+100')


font1 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 15)
font3 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 8, weight = 'bold')
font2 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 20, weight = 'bold')

def aaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
    Ecrire('',Light)

def aaaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#C47ED6")
    Ecrire('',Dark)

def strl(list):
    
        list ="".join(list)
        return list

pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

a =95
b =95

theme = 0
t = 0

ecrit = []
nombre_de_multdiv = 0
nombre_de_sous_add = 0

def Del(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[-1]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Del_all(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[:]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Ecrire(symbole,self):

    ecrit.append(symbole)
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)


def Ecrire_Resulat(valeur,self):
    valeur = strl(valeur)
    self.label1['text'] = valeur

def Calcul(self):
    global nombre_de_multdiv
    global nombre_de_sous_add

    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '/' or ecrit[i] == '*':
            nombre_de_multdiv +=1
    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':
            nombre_de_sous_add +=1

    for i in range(nombre_de_multdiv):

        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '*' or ecrit[i] == '/':

                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):

                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':

                        nb +=1

                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                for i in range(numero):

                    i = -i

                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':

                        nbb -=1

                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='*':
                    resultat = nombre1 * nombre2

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))


                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 / nombre1

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]
                for i in range(len(resultat)):

                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])
                    
                break

    for i in range(nombre_de_sous_add):

        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':

                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):


                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':

                        nb +=1

                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                for i in range(numero):

                    i = -i

                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':

                        nbb -=1

                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='+':
                    resultat = nombre1 + nombre2

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))


                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 - nombre1

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]

                for i in range(len(resultat)):

                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])

                break
    Ecrire_Resulat(ecrit,self)


class Theme():

    def move_window(self,event):

        win.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root - self.x, event.y_root - self.y))

    def set_xy(self,event):

        self.x=event.x_root - win.winfo_x()
        self.y=event.y_root - win.winfo_y()
        return self.x,self.y;

    def boutontheme(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf)
        if self.t == 0:
            Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")
            self.t = 1
            Ecrire('',Light)
        else:
            Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
            self.t = 0
            Ecrire('',Dark)



    def openmenu(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        if self.ouvert == False:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colore)
            if self.t == 0:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
            else:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
            
            self.b_theme_dark.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 25)
            self.b_theme_light.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 45) 
            self.ouvert = True
            return;

        if self.ouvert == True:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colorb)
            self.b_theme_dark.destroy()
            self.b_theme_light.destroy()
            self.ouvert = False 
            return;

    def __init__(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):

        
        if colora == '#18181F':
            self.t = 0
        else:
            self.t = 1

        self.ouvert = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y=0

        #creation menu

        self.canvas_menu = Canvas(win, width =500, height =25, bg = colora, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit = Canvas(bg = colora,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit.create_oval(0,0,20,20, fill= colore,width = 0)
        self.exit.create_text(10, 10, text="x", fill = colord, font= font3)
        self.exit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: win.destroy())

        #affichage menu

        self.exit.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 475, y = 2)
        self.canvas_menu.grid(row = 0,column = 0, columnspan = 5)

        #creation des canvas

        self.canvas_screen = Canvas(win, width =500, height =100, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_num = Canvas(win, width =300, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_op = Canvas(win, width =200, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        #affchage des canvas

        self.canvas_screen.grid(row = 1,column = 0, columnspan = 5)
        self.canvas_keyb_num.grid(row = 2,column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 4)
        self.canvas_keyb_op.grid(row = 2,column = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 4)

        # creation des boutons

        self.b1 = Button(win, text ='1',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('1',self))
        self.b2 = Button(win, text ='2',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('2',self))
        self.b3 = Button(win, text ='3',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('3',self))
        self.b4 = Button(win, text ='4',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('4',self))
        self.b5 = Button(win, text ='5',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('5',self))
        self.b6 = Button(win, text ='6',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('6',self))
        self.b7 = Button(win, text ='7',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('7',self))
        self.b8 = Button(win, text ='8',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('8',self))
        self.b9 = Button(win, text ='9',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('9',self))
        self.b_point = Button(win, text ='.',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('.',self))
        self.b0 = Button(win, text ='0',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('0',self))
        
        self.b_plus = Button(win, text ='+',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('+',self))
        self.b_moins = Button(win, text ='-',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('-',self))
        self.b_fois = Button(win, text ='*',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('*',self))
        self.b_diviser = Button(win, text ='/',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('/',self))
        self.b_del = Button(win, text ='DEL',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del(self))
        self.b_del_all = Button(win, text ='CE',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del_all(self))
        self.b_egale = Button(win, text ='=',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colore,activebackground =colorf,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = 295 ,font = font1,command= lambda: Calcul(self))

        #affichage des nombres

        #colone 1

        self.b7.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.b4.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        self.b1.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
        self.b_point.grid(column = 0, row = 5)

        #colone 2

        self.b8.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.b5.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.b2.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
        self.b0.grid(column = 1, row = 5)

        #colone 3

        self.b9.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.b6.grid(column = 2, row = 3)
        self.b3.grid(column = 2, row = 4)

        #operateurs

        self.b_plus.grid(column = 3, row = 2)
        self.b_moins.grid(column = 4, row = 2)
        self.b_fois.grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        self.b_diviser.grid(column = 4, row = 3)
        self.b_del.grid(column = 3, row = 4)
        self.b_del_all.grid(column = 4, row = 4)
        self.b_egale.grid(column = 2, row = 5,columnspan = 3)

        #ecriture

        self.label1 = tk.Label(win, text = '', justify = tk.RIGHT,font = font2,bg =colorb,fg = colord)
        self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)
        self.b_theme = tk.Button(win, text = 'Themes',font = font3,bg =colorb,fg = colord,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 50,activebackground =colore,command= lambda: self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
        self.b_theme.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 2)

        self.canvas_menu.bind('<1>', self.set_xy)

        self.canvas_menu.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_window)

if theme == 0:
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
else:
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")

win.title('calculator')



win.resizable(height=False,width=False)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it doesn't open a tab, what is disappearing?

Comment: the app is open so a tab need to be open (in the bottom bar) but nothing... sorry im french so its difficult to me but for exemple when you open the terminal app a tab appears at the bottom of your screen but when i open my app...nothing ...

Comment: When you call `overrideredirect()` it removes all window manager decorations from the window, so that it cannot be moved, resized, iconified, or closed in the usual ways — this means you must provide alternative ways of doing any of those things yourself. No one can help you without seeing the code, however it should be a [mre] **not** your whole application.

Comment: @martineau ok thank you! I have made my own function to close and move the window. I give you my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `overridedirect(True)` to remove the window manager decorations, as I said in a comment, you will need to provide some means of doing some or all of them yourself if you still want their functionality. You have done that for closing and moving the window, but you need to do more to make it appear on the Windows taskbar.

This can be accomplished by creating a invisible `root` window that **doesn't** need to have `overridedirect(True)` applied to it, and then create a separate `Toplevel` window for your application (and apply `overridedirect` to it).

The code changes to do all that appears at the very beginning. However you'll also need to make a few other minor changes to the `Theme` class' `__init__()` method to get everything working properly under this new scheme (starting where the `#creation menu` comment is). There's also a couple changes at the very end.

Below is your code with all these changes needed. Note I did *not* turn it into an .exe, so your mileage may vary.

```
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
import os
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font


# Create an invisible root window.
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)

# Create a Toplevel for the application.
win = tk.Toplevel(root)
win.overrideredirect(True)
win.geometry('+400+100')

# Make root forward taskbar minimize and restore events to Toplevel instance.
root.bind("<Unmap>", lambda _: win.withdraw())
root.bind("<Map>", lambda _: win.deiconify())


font1 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 15)
font3 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 8, weight = 'bold')
font2 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 20, weight = 'bold')

def aaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
    Ecrire('',Light)

def aaaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#C47ED6")
    Ecrire('',Dark)

def strl(list):

        list ="".join(list)
        return list

pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

a =95
b =95

theme = 0
t = 0

ecrit = []
nombre_de_multdiv = 0
nombre_de_sous_add = 0

def Del(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[-1]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Del_all(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[:]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Ecrire(symbole,self):

    ecrit.append(symbole)
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)


def Ecrire_Resulat(valeur,self):
    valeur = strl(valeur)
    self.label1['text'] = valeur

def Calcul(self):
    global nombre_de_multdiv
    global nombre_de_sous_add

    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '/' or ecrit[i] == '*':
            nombre_de_multdiv +=1
    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':
            nombre_de_sous_add +=1

    for i in range(nombre_de_multdiv):
        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '*' or ecrit[i] == '/':
                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):
                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':
                        nb +=1
                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':
                        break

                for i in range(numero):
                    i = -i
                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':
                        nbb -=1
                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':
                        break

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='*':
                    resultat = nombre1 * nombre2
                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)
                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))
                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 / nombre1
                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)
                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]
                for i in range(len(resultat)):
                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])
                break

    for i in range(nombre_de_sous_add):
        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':
                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):
                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':
                        nb +=1
                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':
                        break

                for i in range(numero):
                    i = -i
                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':
                        nbb -=1
                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':
                        break

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='+':
                    resultat = nombre1 + nombre2
                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)
                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))
                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 - nombre1
                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)
                    resultat = list(str(round(resultat,5)))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]
                for i in range(len(resultat)):
                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])
                break

    Ecrire_Resulat(ecrit,self)


class Theme:
    def move_window(self,event):
        win.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root - self.x, event.y_root - self.y))

    def set_xy(self,event):
        self.x=event.x_root - win.winfo_x()
        self.y=event.y_root - win.winfo_y()
        return self.x,self.y;

    def boutontheme(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf)
        if self.t == 0:
            Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")
            self.t = 1
            Ecrire('',Light)
        else:
            Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
            self.t = 0
            Ecrire('',Dark)

    def openmenu(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        if self.ouvert == False:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colore)
            if self.t == 0:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
            else:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))

            self.b_theme_dark.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 25)
            self.b_theme_light.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 45)
            self.ouvert = True
            return;

        if self.ouvert == True:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colorb)
            self.b_theme_dark.destroy()
            self.b_theme_light.destroy()
            self.ouvert = False
            return;

    def __init__(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        if colora == '#18181F':
            self.t = 0
        else:
            self.t = 1

        self.ouvert = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y=0

        #creation menu

        self.canvas_menu = Canvas(win, width =500, height =25, bg = colora, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
#        self.exit = Canvas(bg = colora,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit = Canvas(win, bg = colora,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit.create_oval(0,0,20,20, fill= colore,width = 0)
        self.exit.create_text(10, 10, text="x", fill = colord, font= font3)
#        self.exit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: win.destroy())
        self.exit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: root.destroy())

        #affichage menu

        self.exit.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 475, y = 2)
        self.canvas_menu.grid(row = 0,column = 0, columnspan = 5)

        #creation des canvas

        self.canvas_screen = Canvas(win, width =500, height =100, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_num = Canvas(win, width =300, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_op = Canvas(win, width =200, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        #affchage des canvas

        self.canvas_screen.grid(row = 1,column = 0, columnspan = 5)
        self.canvas_keyb_num.grid(row = 2,column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 4)
        self.canvas_keyb_op.grid(row = 2,column = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 4)

        # creation des boutons

        self.b1 = Button(win, text ='1',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('1',self))
        self.b2 = Button(win, text ='2',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('2',self))
        self.b3 = Button(win, text ='3',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('3',self))
        self.b4 = Button(win, text ='4',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('4',self))
        self.b5 = Button(win, text ='5',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('5',self))
        self.b6 = Button(win, text ='6',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('6',self))
        self.b7 = Button(win, text ='7',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('7',self))
        self.b8 = Button(win, text ='8',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('8',self))
        self.b9 = Button(win, text ='9',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('9',self))
        self.b_point = Button(win, text ='.',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('.',self))
        self.b0 = Button(win, text ='0',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('0',self))

        self.b_plus = Button(win, text ='+',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('+',self))
        self.b_moins = Button(win, text ='-',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('-',self))
        self.b_fois = Button(win, text ='*',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('*',self))
        self.b_diviser = Button(win, text ='/',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('/',self))
        self.b_del = Button(win, text ='DEL',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del(self))
        self.b_del_all = Button(win, text ='CE',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del_all(self))
        self.b_egale = Button(win, text ='=',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colore,activebackground =colorf,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = 295 ,font = font1,command= lambda: Calcul(self))

        #affichage des nombres

        #colone 1

        self.b7.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.b4.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        self.b1.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
        self.b_point.grid(column = 0, row = 5)

        #colone 2

        self.b8.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.b5.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.b2.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
        self.b0.grid(column = 1, row = 5)

        #colone 3

        self.b9.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.b6.grid(column = 2, row = 3)
        self.b3.grid(column = 2, row = 4)

        #operateurs

        self.b_plus.grid(column = 3, row = 2)
        self.b_moins.grid(column = 4, row = 2)
        self.b_fois.grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        self.b_diviser.grid(column = 4, row = 3)
        self.b_del.grid(column = 3, row = 4)
        self.b_del_all.grid(column = 4, row = 4)
        self.b_egale.grid(column = 2, row = 5,columnspan = 3)

        #ecriture

        self.label1 = tk.Label(win, text = '', justify = tk.RIGHT,font = font2,bg =colorb,fg = colord)
        self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)
        self.b_theme = tk.Button(win, text = 'Themes',font = font3,bg =colorb,fg = colord,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 50,activebackground =colore,command= lambda: self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
        self.b_theme.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 2)

        self.canvas_menu.bind('<1>', self.set_xy)
        self.canvas_menu.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_window)

if theme == 0:
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
else:
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")

#win.title('calculator')
win.master.title('Calculator')
#win.resizable(height=False,width=False)  # Not needed with overrideredirect.
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you soooo much but one last thing ... why I have to click 4 times before the windows can be re-opened

Comment: **update** : i have made some test and I have to close the windows with th tab to re-opened it because just click somewhere else is not considered as an `<Unmap>` event by tkinter... do I have an other way to do an event went I go somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes, `<Map>` events have to do with visibility. Perhaps you need to handle `<FocusIn>` and `<Focusout>` events, too. See accepted answer to question [Tkinter - window focus loss event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567324/tkinter-window-focus-loss-event). Let me know.

Comment: Another pair might be `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`. See [Event types](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html) for a good reference.

Comment: ooooh thank you sooooo much I didn't know this event !

Comment: its work perfectly with the `FocusOut` event and thank you for the site! I used to use another site and he was so bad, this will help me!

Comment: You're welcome. We *both* learned a few things working on this…